# In HTML5 How can I align my header the way I need to

Tags: html, css

I'm currently practicing some HTML 5 Web App development, but I can't even get my header to align properly.

visit http://www.sithhappens.net to see what I mean, (view page source to see my html)
and http://www.sithhappens.net/iphone.css
to see the CSS

I want the "Route.me" to align middle, and button (which is just a place holder till I implement a button there) to stay to the left. Thanks.

(Visit the webpage on your mobile device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct HTML, I have injected the styling into the HTML so you can see how it is done.  The trick is to make the button position: absolute so it does not affect the spacing of the text "Route.Me".

```
<article>
<header><button style="
    position: absolute;
">Button</button> <div align="center" style="display: block; text-align: center;">Route.Me </div>
</header>
</article>
```

Comment: Where might I do that I don't see the button.

Comment: One more question if you take a look at the page now can you tell me why the Menu button text is offset?

Comment: You forgot position absolute on the menu button.

Comment: i have it in the CSS for the entire button ,you can see it at the link in the original question to the iphone.css

Answer (score 1):

use only

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top:-20px;">Route Me</div>
```

Comment: He wants the button text to stay on the left and the Route.Me to be cetnered.  Your approach will center both.

Comment: All that did was create a new line now I have 2 lines for my header?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to place `button` text in a `<p>` element. Set styles like this:

```
<div class="btn">Button</div>
<div align="center" class="txt" >Route.Me </div>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
    float:left;
}

.txt {
    display:block;
}
```